# ! No room for a new \skip

Tags: errors, eledmac

I just did a new `TeX Live` install on another machine, but my project doesn't compile:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everysel.sty))
! No room for a new \skip .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.3446 ...r\newseries\expandafter{\default@series}
```

I tried

```
\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
```

as second and third line of my file, but it didn't work, so I commented it back out.

then

```
? h
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

I guess I could need some help with that...

Typing E at the error prompt gets me into `eledmac.sty`.

Edit: I have minimised my example further.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac}
\begin{document}
something
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you running a loop that reserves new skip registers?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not that I'm aware of that.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How would I detect that? The same project builds fine on other machines with `TeX Live` installs a few weeks old.

Comment: Each new skip is reported to the `.log` file in the form `.... = \skipXY` where `XY` is an integer number

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I grepped my logfile for `skip`s, it reserves 299 of them for apparently different things and then fails at the 300th of them.

Comment: Actually, you should have 2^15 skip registers and you're not even close to that number. Try explicitly `pdflatex -etex` perhaps. And you should post the code

Comment: I am using `xelatex` and the `-etex` option doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Please, make a full example showing the issue.

Comment: @egreg When I tried loading `etex` it was the second line of my file, thus before loading `eledmac`.

Comment: @muk.li Note that `eledmac` has been superseded by `reledmac`; it may be a problem due to the fact that the most recent LaTeX kernel doesn't need loading `etex` any more, but `eledmac` has not been updated for this. Try `\RequirePackage{etex}` *before* `\documentclass`.

Comment: @egreg I now have a minimum example reproducing the problem by loading all packages of my real project. I'm copying this into my question.

Comment: I get no error, sorry. Update your TeX distribution and remove the call to `etex` (and the `\reserveinserts` instruction). Also remove `xlxtra` and `xunicode` that do nothing useful.

Comment: @egreg This is a completely fresh `TeX Live` install. On other machines with installs a few weeks old I don't get this error either. This machine being a virtual server, could there maybe be some endianness issues? I remember having some weird irreproducible issues on it with something else.

Comment: @muk.li It's probably a fresh install *without updates*.

Comment: @egreg `tlmgr: no updates available`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not ever need to load `etex.sty` these days, but if you do load it is best to load it first.

`(r)eledmac` have been updated to use the latex extended allocation scheme so if you get the latest

```
\ProvidesPackage{eledmac}[2015/10/05 v1.24.9 LaTeX port of EDMAC]%
```

version of `eledmac` then you can use

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac}
\begin{document}
something
\end{document}
```

With older versions of `eledmac` you need to load `etex.sty` early and reserve more inserts when using current latex:

```
\RequirePackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{40}
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac}
\begin{document}
something
\end{document}
```

Comment: see my comment, Thanks David for your help.

Comment: @Maïeul I think I'm confused over the relationship between elemac and reledmac, but no matter:-)

Comment: reledmac is just the version 2.x of eledmac (which was the version 1.x of ledmac). I do not maintain anymore eledmac, except for minor points for compatibility with new release of LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

What David said is partially true. The last version of eledmac has been updated.

However, a better way is to use the optimization options of (r)eledmac to disable series you do not need.

For example if you need only series A and you do not need familiar notes, do:

```
\usepackage[noreledmac,series={A},nofamiliar]{eledmac}
```

read § 11 of the handbook.

Answer (score 2):

David Carlisle found a way to solve this problem directly in (r)eledmac code. The version 1.24.9, just send on the CTAN, solve this issue, without needed to

```
\RequirePackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{40}
```

before the `\documentclass`

The version 2.2.1 fixes for reledmac.

What I have said about option like

```
\usepackage[series={A},nofamiliar]{eledmac}
```

is still available, as it will provdie a faster version of (r)eledmac.

Comment: thanks I just checked ctan version and confirm this works, I'll update my answer. I guess it will be in texlive tomorrow.